# Kafka stream application not consume data after restart

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

After I did restart our Kafka cluster my application of Kafka streams didn't receive messages from input topic and I got an `exception` of `"can׳t create internal topic"`. After some research, I did reset with the Kafka tool (to the input topic and the application) the tool is `Kafka-streams-application-reset.sh`.

Unfortunately, it didn't resolve the problem and I also got the `exception` again

Comment: Hard to say without stack trace -- is the cluster itself up an running with enough nodes? What replication factor do you use? What broker and streams version do you use?

Comment: does **auto.create.topics.enable** enabled?

Comment: The following gist is the stack trace @MatthiasJ.Sax  our version is 1.0.0 and all about the cluster are fine (according to the monitor) replica factor for streams is 1.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/orenpx/6da8a9d928e7affc90648c601fec6b85

Comment: @Jacky Yes we keep the default , I understood that is not relevant for streams because it run a topic create command and the configuration is relevant just when you try to read/write fro or to not exist topic. but maybe I am wrong

Comment: Can you check the logs? There should be a WARN level log like `Could not create internal topics: ` exposing more information. The exception you see is thrown, after retries are exceeded -- the WARN log should contain the actual root cause why it was not possible to create the topic.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax `2018-04-11T17:14:51.581087000Z [2018-04-11 17:14:51,580] WARN [AnomalySignatureStreamJobanomaly-predictor-us-central1-a-20-anomalypredictor_8_1-StreamThread-169] stream-thread [Timer-10] Could not create internal topics: Existing internal topic AnomalySignatureStream-KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000055-repartition has invalid partitions. Expected: 150 Actual: 1. Use 'kafka.tools.StreamsResetter' tool to clean up invalid topics before processing. Retry #4 (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopicManager)`

Answer (score 3):

From the error message, you can infer that the topic already exists and thus, cannot be created. The reason for the failure is, that the existing topic does not have the expected number of partitions (it has 1 instead of 150) -- if the number of partitions would match, Kafka Streams would just use the existing topic.

This can happen, if you have topic auto-create enabled at the brokers (and the topic was created with a wrong number of partitions), or if the number of partitions of your input topic changed. Kafka Streams does not automatically change the number of partitions for the repartition topic, because this might result in data corruption and thus lead to incorrect results.

One way to fix this, it to either manually delete this topic: note, that this might result in data loss and you should only do this, if you know that it is what you want.

Another (better way) would be, to reset the application cleanly using `bin/kafka-streams-application-reste.sh` in combination with `KafkaStreams#cleanup()`.

Because you need to clean up the application and users should be aware of the implication, Kafka Streams fails to make user aware of the issue instead of "auto magically" take some actions that might be undesired from a user point of view.

Check out the docs for more details. There is also a blog post that explains application reset in details:

- https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application/

Comment: I did reset and also my application call to cleanup(). This error occurred also after the reset. some more strange behavior is that after the reset all 150 partitions deleted but after few seconds it appeared with 1 partition and the application is down so it is not because the auto create